# Testing if a value is in a column MYSQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am making a secret santa program that when you click the button draw it will

1. check to see if the person who is drawing does not match the person drawn
2. check to see if the person who is drawn has not already been drawn
3. check to see if the person drawing has not already drawn before

I have 1 & 2 down but I am not sure how to approach #3.

The basic idea is test a column (called giftfirst) to see if there is a value that matches the drawn name, and the table is called list.

Any additional information you need go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a `$_COOKIE` in client's machine and check if it is present then he has `already drawn before`.